# Why are posts deleted because of spam/offensive flags still automatically locked?

Tags: discussion, deleted-posts, locked

Posts that get deleted because of spam or offensive flags are [automatically deleted and locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780017/cheap-ssl-certificates) by [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community).

I guess this is a holdover from the old days when users were able to easily undelete their own posts, but now that you can no longer undelete any post deleted by a moderator, I think the automatic lock is no longer necessary.

Comment: Although it might not be necessary, what would be gained by not locking it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, strictly-speaking it's not *necessary* anymore.

It does send a rather clear message though, eh? I mean, you can't even *edit* the post. Mod-deletion at least gives you the option of improving, flagging, and seeing it undeleted, but community flag-deletion *salts the earth*.